# concatenating file path to changing folders

Tags: matlab, dicom

I am somewhat new to MATLAB and am trying to set up a changing file path in a loop to go into a series of folders and grab image files from each folder. I'm not sure if the problem is with the concatenated parts of the path itself, or with the wildcard search I am using.

I've used similar changing file paths before that have worked, but this one is giving me a `"Index exceeds matrix dimensions"` error. I thought it was the '*' element that was problematic (similar concatenated paths have worked for me, but only when I specify a file extension or part of a file name), but I am trying to grab DICOM files that do not have any extension, which might make it difficult.

The line within the for loop is as follows:

```
inputs{1, crun} = cellstr(spm_select('FPList'[allinput,'T1Rawunzip',filesep,OrderForDicoms3{crun,1}],'*'));
```

I've tried different ways of specifying this--using spm_select, not using spm_select, using commas instead of filesep or vice versa, but nothing has worked.

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

(for reference:
`crun` is the counter the moves the loop forward, `'allinput'` is a previously-specified path, `OrderForDicoms3` is a .mat file with a list of folder names that are being individually concatenated to the path each time the loop runs)

Thanks!

-Victoria

Comment: The `index exceeds...` error means that one of you are trying to get data from an array outside the defined bounds of that array. I bet it has something to do with `OrderForDicoms3`... what is the value of `crun` and the size of `OrderForDicoms3` when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the most general approach of grabbing files from a folder. If you specify the input folder through `uigetdir`, then all the files can be grabbed using `dir` command:

```
folder = uigetdir;
files = dir(folder);
for i =1:length(files)
    if(~files.isdir())
          filename = fullfile(folder, files(i).name);
          % ... read in the data %
    end
end
```

You can always do it for multiple levels.